# Array Initialization from a struct

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering if there was a way to initialize an array out of a variable from a struct.  Say you have a struct like this-

```
struct Test{  
    int Number;  
};
```

And you wanted to initialize the int **Number** to become an array.
I've already tried this, and it doesn't work:

```
Test t1;  
t1.Number = new int[3];   
t1.Number[3] = 6;
```

I know ISO C++ forbids resizing arrays, but if there was a way to initialize the integer to be an array, that's not really resizing(isn't it?)
Also, vectors don't work inside of structs.  I get a "*Vector does not name a type*" error.

***P.S.***, I can't do this either:

```
struct Test{  
    int Number[5];  
};
```

Because at that time I don't know the size of the array I want.

Comment: How could an `int` magically become an array? It would need to be an `int*` at the least, but even then you'd best steer clear and look at `std::vector<>` instead.

Comment: @ildjarn That's right, it doesn't.  That only works if you use a pointer.  But I think the 'std::vector<>' approach is a better idea.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

vector works just fine in structs:

```
#include <vector>

struct Test {
    std::vector<int> Numbers;
};
```

I'm not sure what you're really trying to do but I think this comes close.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *pointer* to `int` -- i.e.,

```
struct Test{  
    int *Number;  
};
```

Then you can assign this at any future time to point to an array of your preferred size:

```
t.Number = new int[5];
```

But as other posters have already said, `std::vector`, with a small "v", works fine; be sure to `#include <vector>` so the compiler knows what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

One trick to do this

```
struct Test {
  int Numbers[1];
};
```

when you initialize the struct, you need to use your own allocation function.

```
struct Test *NewTest(int sizeOfNumbers) {
  return (struct Test*)malloc(sizeof(struct Test) + sizeof(int)*(sizeOfNumbers - 1));
}
```

then, you will be able to access the numbers by using,

```
struct Test *test1 = NewTest(10);
test1->Numbers[0]...
test1->Numbers[1]...
test1->Numbers[9]...
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `new int[3]` is an `int*` not an `int`. To make your code work you can do:

```
struct Test {  
    int* Number;  
};

int main() {
    Test t1;  
    t1.Number = new int[4]; // Note this should be 4 so that index 3 isn't out of bounds
    t1.Number[3] = 6;
    delete t1.Number;

    return 0;
}
```

However you should really use a `std::vector` rather than a static array. Vectors work just fine inside structs:

```
#include <vector>

struct Test {  
    std::vector<int> Number;  
};

int main() {
    Test t1;  
    t1.Number.resize(4);   
    t1.Number[3] = 6;

    return 0;
}
```